# Trouble with lines between HTML table cells showing up on iOS

Tags: html, css, ios, html-table

I have a table (one row shown on image) that has a box-shadow and all borders set to none.
Unfortunately, on iOS you can see these very light lines between table cells (three  in a row).

They could be coming from the box-shadow, but I'm not sure why there is any space at all between the s!

[image: Light lines showing up between table cells.]

```
/* For spacing between rows */

table {
    border-collapse: seperate;
    border-spacing: 0 15px;
}


/* For rounded edges on each row */

td:first-child {
    border-radius: 21px 0 0 21px;
    -moz-border-radius: 21px 0 0 21x;
    -webkit-border-radius: 21px 0 0 21px;
    width: 10%;
}


/* For rounded edges on each row */

td:last-child {
    border-radius: 0 21px 21px 0;
    -moz-border-radius: 0 21px 21px 0;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0 21px 21px 0;
}

td {
    background: var(--main-bg);
    padding: 20px;
    box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The lines are actually the shadows applied to `td`. And there's no space between the cells. Its because of different `z-index` of each cell, ie, they are overlapping.

Comment: I see! That makes sense, thanks. Is it possible to set the z-index to the same amount to get ride of the shadows, or should I for example reverse the z-indexes from right to left?

Comment: Applying same `z-index` won't work. You can add the shadow to `<table>` instead. That way, there won't be any lines.